# Multiplying nth character in Java String by 2 using stream and reduce?

Tags: java, java-8, integer, java-stream, reduce

Trying to use Java streams and reduce for this piece of code

```
//get string as char array
char[] chars = ccNumber.toCharArray();
// build array list to store integer value of each char
List<Integer> multipliedChars = new ArrayList<>();
//get char values on even positions of the array, multiply them by two and add them to array list
for (int i = 1; i < chars.length; i+=2) {
    multipliedChars.add((chars[i] * 2) / 10);
}
```

**Java 8 version**

```
return IntStream.range(0, ccNumber.length())
            .filter(n -> n % 2 != 0)
            .map(ccNumber::charAt)
            .reduce(1 , (x) -> (x * 2) / 10)
            .sum();
```

However it is complaining that my arguments in the reduce method are incompatible with what I am trying to do?

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: What are you trying to do: collect elements in a list, or calculate a sum? Types aside, the two approaches do very different things.

Comment: side note: you dont need reduce but reduce takes two parameters and return one in your case IntBinaryOperator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Originally I was thinking that we need to use second `map` method here. But actually we still can use `reduce`:

```
IntStream.range(0, str.length())
            .filter(n -> n % 2 != 0)
            .map(str::charAt)
            .reduce(0, (result,next) -> result + next / 5));
```

according to  javadocs [reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html)

```
reduce(
       0,
       (result, next) -> result + next / 5)
```

> The `reduce` operation takes two arguments:
>
> `identity`: The identity element is both the initial value of the reduction and the default result if there are no elements in the
>   stream. In this example, the identity element is 0; this is the
>   initial value of the sum and the default value if no members
>   exist in the collection.
>
> `accumulator`: The accumulator function takes two parameters: a partial result of the reduction (in this example, the sum of all
>   processed integers so far) and the next element of the stream (in this
>   example, an integer). It returns a new partial result. In this
>   example, the accumulator function is a lambda expression that adds two
>   Integer values and returns an Integer value:
>
> ```
> (result, next) -> result + next * / 5)
> ```

Now we can do the same thing using second `map` instead of `reduce` :

```
IntStream.range(0, str.length())
            .filter(n -> n % 2 != 0)
            .map(str::charAt)
            .map(x -> x  / 5)
            .sum();
```

result is going to be  identical:

```
assert  IntStream.range(0, str.length())
                .filter(n -> n % 2 != 0)
                .map(str::charAt)
                .map(x -> x  / 5)
                .sum()
                ==
        IntStream.range(0, str.length())
                .filter(n -> n % 2 != 0)
                .map(str::charAt)
                .reduce(0, (result, next) -> result + next / 5);
```

But if you need to collect values, we need to use `map`:

```
IntStream.range(0, str.length())
                .filter(n -> n % 2 != 0)
                .map(str::charAt)
                .map(x -> x / 5).boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As @Holger pointed below in the comments " dividing by ten still does not make any sense. But anyway, multiplying with two, followed by dividing by ten, is the same as dividing by five"

Comment: Also reduce becomes terminal operation since its using identity seed and returns primitive

Comment: I think, `sum()` should be replaced with `collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov, I added example with a list as well. Thanks a lot

Comment: Like in the OP’s other question, dividing by ten still does not make any sense. But anyway, multiplying with two, followed by dividing by ten, is the same as dividing by five and besides rounding issues, there is no difference between dividing each element by five before summing and dividing the sum of all elements. It would be really interesting to learn about the actual use case, to understand which variant would solve the actual problem.

Comment: @Holger, I didn't pay close attention to the formula in the original question. Which I should have done. You are perfectly right! I will update my answer.